# How to dynamically bind Tipsy tooltip on the Title attribute with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, tipsy

Ok so I made myself a directive for jQuery Tipsy, it's working as I want it but I got a little problem with the title. I want my title to be sometime filled, sometime blank depending on a selected option (dropdown), so it's very dynamic. I do have something working with `ng-attr-title` but it seems to only do the job once.

Here is my directive:

```
.directive('ngxTipsy', function() {
    // jQuery Tipsy Tooltip
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            // possible directions:
            // nw | n | ne | w | e | sw | s | se
            element.tipsy({ 
                delayIn:0, 
                delayOut:0, 
                gravity: attrs.ngxTipsy, 
                opacity: 1, 
                html: true
            });
        }
    }
})
```

and here is some sample HTML code:

```
<select name="type" class="form-control" ng-model="mytype">
    <option value="type1">Type 1</option>   
    <option value="type2">Type 2</option>
</select>

<input type="number" name="price" ngx-tipsy="s" ng-attr-title="{{ (mytype == 'type1') ? 'some title' : '' }}" ng-model="myprice">
```

Please note that it does work the first time, if I select type2 directly nothing shows in my tooltip title, then I select type1 and `title` attribute gets filled...that is correct...but then choosing whatever else after, the `title` will never change. It seems that `ng-attr-title` only works once??? I want it to bind all the time, any suggestions?

**Note:**
Please note that my problem is strictly with `ng-attr-title` and/or the `title` attribute and NOT with the directive itself, I only supplied it to show how I implemented it.

Comment: I'm confused about your issue. I originally thought you were having a problem with your directive not updating since you included it, but the problem is entirely with `ng-attr-title`, right? What does `ngx-tipsy` have to do with anything?

Comment: First, I'm new to Angular but I managed to that directive which does work correctly, I think...but yes my problem is strictly on the `ng-attr-title` because it seems to work only the first time, not after... and just to make sure you understand, a Tooltip needs a `title` to work, but depending on my select option (dropdown) I want to fill or empty out that attribute dynamically. My problem is once it's filled, it just stays there indefinitely, I cannot blank it out :(

Comment: Could you make an example on something like jsbin.com and only include the relevant code? I'm not even sure what `ng-attr-title` is. I don't see it anywhere in the docs.

Comment: Could you join me for chat here? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44297/chat-for-ghiscoding I'll be able to solve this.

Comment: Sorry, I went to bed 20min after and now I'm at work, but I think I found my problem which is related to how Tipsy works actually and I just found out. Once Tipsy creates the tooltip, it as well create another attribute called `original-title` which I have to handle after a tooltip is created. I will try it out tonight and maybe rephrase my question to reflect that problem better. Thanks a lot for your help m59

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few trials and errors I got it working, I was trying to update dynamically the `title` attribute but that is not the way to go with Tipsy extension, instead I have to use the `original-title` attribute for anything that is posted **after** the creation of the element that has a tooltip, which you can also call that has the effect of Dynamically Updating Text (like mentioned on Tipsy website). So my code has to change with this instead:

```
<input type="number" name="price" ngx-tipsy="s" ng-attr-original-title="{{ (mytype == 'type1') ? 'some title' : '' }}" title="" ng-model="myprice">
```

I added the `title` attribute in my answer, but it could in fact be removed without affecting the end result. What is most important is to use the attribute of `original-title` and so with angular it becomes `ng-attr-original-title` for a proper binding. It also tells me that my directive was indeed properly built.